# Swagger-play throws exception during app initizalization

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, swagger

I have problem when I'am trying attach Swagger to Play Framework app. Swagger lib scan uninitialized classes and cause problems. Any advices how to deal with it?

I extracted part of app as example:

https://github.com/mgosk/play-swagger-example

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at auth.services.AuthService.<init>(AuthService.scala:24)
  while locating auth.services.AuthService
    for parameter 0 at auth.AnonymousAuthController.<init>(AuthController.scala:16)
  while locating auth.AnonymousAuthController
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:43)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 1 at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl.<init>(SwaggerPlugin.scala:33)
  while locating play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl
  at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule.bindings(SwaggerModule.scala:11):
Binding(interface play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPlugin to ConstructionTarget(class play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
while locating play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPlugin
```

Comment: Have you finally fixed it? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Damian No. I didn't fix it.

Comment: @Damian problem is fixed in newest swagger version

Comment: I am having same issue still with `swagger-play2` version `1.6.1-SNAPSHOT` and play version `2.6.2`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem with `swagger-play2` v1.6.0 and play v2.6.21. Any progress? `Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl.<init>(SwaggerPlugin.scala:35)`

Comment: Library probably need an upgrade. Try to open a ticket on github.

Comment: I did it, but there was no feedback so far. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/issues/185

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed in newest, not documented swagger version. Just use:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.3"
)
```